# How do I create "Send to Email" functionality along with Screenshot?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, html, email

I need to create a webpage which will have following features:

1. It will have a simple calculator.
2. There will be an "Send this calculation to my email" function. User enters his email in a textbox, and we need to send the screenshot of that calculation to his email.

How can that be done?

Comment: it can't. you're going to need more than just html

Comment: Can this HTML form post to a script?  If that's the case then the script could render the calculation into an image that is then emailed to the submitted email address.  The script you use to render the calculation can be any of your favorite.  Otherwise you can instruct your viewer on how to use `Alt+Print Screen` :-P

Comment: Ok. Can you please show me how to do it in ASP.NET? I am not sure how can I take screenshot of the calculation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For taking the screenshot of your screen this is the simple code in C#

To create a screenshot in c# we need to use drawing api of the .net framework

First you have import System.Drawing.Imaging name space with following code...

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

here is the code in C# for screenshot.

```
int screenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Width;
int screenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(new Point(0, 0)).Height;
Bitmap bmpScreenShot = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight);
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmpScreenShot);
gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenWidth, screenHeight));
bmpScreenShot.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: This won't work correctly with multiple monitors, and your app should *definitely* support multiple monitors nowadays.